# What is wrong in my Struts xml file?

Tags: jquery, json, struts2

I am going to submit a form via jQuery AJAX in Struts 2.

struts.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <!DOCTYPE struts PUBLIC
"-//Apache Software Foundation//DTD Struts Configuration 2.0//EN"
"http://struts.apache.org/dtds/struts-2.0.dtd">

<struts>

<constant name="struts.devMode" value="true" />
<constant name="struts.ui.theme" value="simple" />
<package name="default" extends="struts-default">

    <action name="loginSubmit"
        class="com.myproj.portal.controllers.PhysicianLoginController"
        method="execute">
        <result name="success">/landing.jsp</result>
        <result name="failure">/staff-login.jsp</result>
    </action>
    <action name="logout"
        class="com.myproj.portal.controllers.PhysicianLoginController"
        method="logout">
        <result name="success">/Welcome.htm</result>
    </action>
    <action name="demographics"
        class="com.myproj.portal.controllers.DemographicsController"
        method="execute">
        <interceptor-ref name="token" />
        <interceptor-ref name="basicStack" />

        <result name="success">/demographics.jsp</result>
        <result name="failure">/demographics.jsp</result>
        <result name="invalid.token">/demographics.jsp</result>
    </action>       
</package>

<package name="example" extends="struts-default,json-default">  
    <action name="chngpass"  class="com.myproj.portal.controllers.ChangePasswordController"
    method="execute" >
         <result name="success" type="json" />
    </action>
</package>  
  </struts>
```

I have added the JSON plugin jar in my lib folder. But this raises the following error

```
12:40:41,236 ERROR [DomHelper] The content of element type "package" must match "(result-types?,interceptors?,default-intercept
org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: The content of element type "package" must match "(result-types?,interceptors?,default-interceptor-ref?,default-action-ref?,
        at org.apache.xerces.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.createSAXParseException(Unknown Source)
```

Whats wrong with it ?

Comment: I have added this package below another package. But after adding this generates the error.

Comment: Wrong order of elements.

Comment: edit your question by changing the Exception type (and post the whole exception), since that problem is solved.

Answer (score 0):

To get a result type of `json`, you don't need to define the following

```
<result-types>
    <result-type name="json" class="org.apache.struts2.json.JSONResult"/>
</result-types>

<interceptors>
    <interceptor name="json" class="org.apache.struts2.json.JSONInterceptor"/>
</interceptors>
```

Remove the above declarations.

Secondly, your package declaration should be in `struts` element. So in the end, you should have something like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1" ?>

<!DOCTYPE struts PUBLIC
"-//Apache Software Foundation//DTD Struts Configuration 2.0//EN"
"http://struts.apache.org/dtds/struts-2.0.dtd">

<struts>
<package name="example" namespace="/your_name_space" extends="struts-default,json-default">  
    <action name="chngpass"  class="com.myproj.portal.controllers.ChangePasswordController"
    method="execute" >
         <result name="success" type="json" />
    </action>
</package>
</struts>
```

Comment: 14:02:34,169 INFO  [STDOUT] 14:02:34,169 ERROR [Dispatcher] Dispatcher initialization failed
Unable to load configuration. - [unknown location]
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.ConfigurationManager.getConfiguration(ConfigurationManager.java:70)
        at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.init_PreloadConfiguration(Dispatcher.java:446)
        at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.init(Dispatcher.java:490)

Comment: @TuhinSubhraDey Can you post your entire `struts` config.

Comment: @TuhinSubhraDey Can u put the two packages in different namespaces and see if the error throws again. Do this for instance `<package name="default" namespace="/default" extends="struts-default">` and `<package name="example" namespace="/example" extends="struts-default,json-default">` instead of `<package name="default" extends="struts-default">` and `<package name="example"  extends="struts-default,json-default">`

Comment: 18:15:45,296 INFO  [STDOUT] 18:15:45,296 ERROR [Dispatcher] Dispatcher initialization failed
Unable to load configuration. - [unknown location]